# how to handle multiple transaction that create rows that depend in the status of previous records?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dropwizard

So I have a Rest endpoint to create a record in the DB, I'm using the  Unit of work pattern.

Before creating this record the code checks if there is any "active" record in the DB and set it to "inactive" (this is just a column) before creating the new record.

The code to create this record is used inside the app and it is also accessed from external services using the endpoint.

The problem is that I keep getting more than 1 record with status "active" in my database.

It seems sometimes there are multiple transactions hitting this code (maybe a call from inside the app, and other from an external service through the endpoint) and when one of the transactions checks for the "active" records in the DB to set them as "inactive" the other transaction is still not committed so I end up with 2 active records.

Would the usage of a pessimistic lock help me with this case?

Comment: Probably not, and don't call me a lock

Comment: Mysql and postgresql are two different products, with different implementations of sql. Pls add the one back that you actually use - if the database is relevant at all. If you want to handle everything in the orm, then the rdbms is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @Strawberry any suggestion then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for sure would pessimistic lock help!

If you do a `select for update` the other transaction cannot read this record.

But you have to be careful because some RDBMS don't do row locking but something like page locking and it may lock more than a row.

So the transaction should be as short as possible.